# Installing Ubuntu on a new harddrive next to Windows 7 on SSD and raid 0 configurated drives

Tags: grub2, windows

I want to install Ubuntu on a new harddrive next to Windows 7 (which is on some other drive). Here's my layout (click for full-size image, description below)

[image]

- Disk 0: A SSD with Windows 7 on it
- Disk 1: Actually 2 physical HDD's each 500 GB in raid 0
- Disk 2: The new hard drive I installed Ubuntu on (or so I think). I added in red what each partition is.
- Disk 3: The USB stick for installing Ubuntu

I have been busy all morning trying to get this to work, tried many things that people said on here or somewhere else on the web. It just won't work :(

Basically everytime I try to install it in any way possible, Grub messes up and goes into the Grub rescue mode. I have tried to use boot-repair. I can only get my Windows bootloader back using this (or using the Windows 7 DVD), but I just can't get Ubuntu to start.

Windows doesn't want to recognize that I have Ubuntu installed either.
[image]

Basically I boot my BIOS into Disk 0. Right now, Windows boots up normally, without any OS list or whatever. If I try to boot up into any of the other disks except the USB drive or DVD drive, I get the GRUB rescue screen...

---

The **Boot Info Summary** from Boot-Repair is at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6102240/

Any tips or hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by doing the following.

Just to make sure I backed up everything on the Raid 0 drives!

- I physically detached the Raid 0 drives. Only the SDD and the new HDD were now connected.
- I reinstalled Ubuntu on the new hard disk.
- Rebooted and in the BIOS set the new HDD as primary boot.
- Now I got the GRUB2 menu. Checked if I could still boot into Windows: no problem.
- After that I booted into Ubuntu and I ran all updates available and shut down the system.
- Reconnected the Raid 0 drives.
- Booted up, ended up in GRUB2 menu like it should. I can now boot into both Ubuntu and Windows using the GRUB2 menu.

Unfortunately I can't see the Raid 0 drive yet in Ubuntu, but this can probably get fixed easily.

Thanks for the help everyone.